# asp.net listview not updating its pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview which has 12 entries.

Each page is set to display a max of 5 so there are 3 pages.

Now each time I click a page number I must click it twice to actually go onto it and also it always displays just the top 5 entries. For example on page 1 and 2 it displays the same first 5 entries (entries 1 - 5) and on page 3 it only displays 2 entries but they are the first 2 entries (entry 1 and 2) not the last (i.e entry 11 and 12)

Why is it not updating?

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly implement paging. In your example, if you wanna display page 2, you skip first 5 entries (which are in the page 1), then take next 5 (page size) entries and display them.

Using LINQ this would look like:

```
entries.Skip(pageNumber * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: I noticed that if I manually add the .DataSource and .DataBind() the above happens but if I use the wizard it works properly. The Reason I cant use the wizard is because I get an error when initializing the page since the method that populates the listview cannot have a value until a value selected from a listbox by the user. How to get around that?

Comment: when you use .DataSource and .DataBind() do you enclose these statements in _if (!IsPostback) { ... your code... }_ statement?